# How do I trigger an event on jQuery Tabs rotate?

Tags: jquery-ui, rotation, jquery-ui-tabs

I've got a slider that's built with [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/):

```
<section id="featured">
    <aside id="sidebar">
        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected">
                <a href="#panel_1">[Tab Heading]</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item">
                <a href="#panel_2">[Tab Heading]</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item">
                <a href="#panel_3">[Tab Heading]</a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item">
                <a href="#panel_4">[Tab Heading]</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <section id="rotate_me">
        <div class="featured_panel" id="panel_1">
            <p>[Tab Content]</p>
        </div>
        <div class="featured_panel ui-tabs-hide" id="panel_2">
            <p>[Tab Content]</p>
        </div>
        <div class="featured_panel ui-tabs-hide" id="panel_3">
            <p>[Tab Content]</p>
        </div>
        <div class="featured_panel ui-tabs-hide" id="panel_4">
            <p>[Tab Content]</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script>$('#featured').tabs('rotate', 4000, false);</script>
```

The client wants the tabs to rotate through just the first and second tabs.

I added a function to the `show` event:

```
.tabs({
    show: function(event, ui) {
        var selected = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );
        if (selected == 3) {
            $( "#featured" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 1 );
        }
    }
})
```

but this did nothing.

Any idea how I could make the slider rotate through just the first and second tab?

Comment: I looked through the other questions on jQuery tabs, but didn't find any relevant information to my specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selected` option only applies to initialization. You could simply trigger a click on the first tab.

```
$("#featured li.ui-tabs-nav-item:first").trigger("click");
```

Comment: There was a problem in my code; I had entered a selector incorrectly.  The jQuery UI Tabs documentation says that the `selected` option can be used after init to change the tab, so with my selector corrected, my code works.  Just for kicks I tried yours out and it works as well.